# PHP: Open redirection in New Browser Window. Possible/How?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I hope you can help me. We have script to redirect people on our Network. If a person had accepted our terms, they are redirected to a News Page of ours.

Now we would prefer that this redirection, as an action of accepting the terms by clicking on a button `<a href="<?php print $grant_url ?>">` will open in a complete new Browser Window (not a pop-up)

Can we use window.open? and How?

Comment: Does the client side know when the terms should be shown or not? If not, you could perform a synchronous AJAX request to find out and then use `window.open()` to show the terms.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP or redirects, since the window behavior is controlled on the client side. You'd need to change HTML / javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the used that logged to your system you can check if he agreed to your terms or whatever, then when he click you will you window open or header with the parameters you need with the specific  target  window.open("x.PHP?var=&Var=,target")

Comment: The client side does not have to know anything about accepted terms. The user just 'clicktrhough' by hitting a button. Behind this button, a PHP script is used:

      $base_grant_url = urldecode($_GET['base_grant_url']);
      $user_continue_url = urldecode($_GET['user_continue_url']);
      $override_continue_url = 'http://nu.nl';
      
      $override_the_users_request = false;
      if ($override_the_users_request) {
        $grant_url = $base_grant_url . "?continue_url=" . urlencode($override_continue_url) . "&duration=3600";
      }

Now in this script I would like to force open new ..